# Plone 3.3.5 Document_view attribute error

Tags: plone, upgrade

Plone n00b here, continuing migration issues from 2.5 to 3.3.5.

To eliminate any potential problems I cleared out the custom folder and tried to get the pages to show up.  When I go to a page that isn't the front page I get an:

```
AttributeError _v_transform.
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Exception traceback
Time    2012/09/13 08:18:06.733 GMT-7
User Name (User Id) Anonymous User (None)
Request URL http://localhost:8080/mission-vision/index_html/document_view

Exception Type  AttributeError
Exception Value _v_transform
Traceback (innermost last): 
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 119, in publish 
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 88, in mapply 
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 42, in call_object 
Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 313, in __call__ 
Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 350, in _bindAndExec 
Module Products.CMFCore.FSPageTemplate, line 216, in _exec 
Module Products.CMFCore.FSPageTemplate, line 155, in pt_render 
Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplate, line 98, in pt_render 
Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 117, in pt_render 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__ 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 891, in do_useMacro 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 957, in do_defineSlot 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 861, in do_defineMacro 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 957, in do_defineSlot 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 949, in do_defineSlot 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 861, in do_defineMacro 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 586, in do_setLocal_tal 
Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
URL: file:d:\websites\nipo\plone 3.3.5\buildout-cache\eggs\plone-3.3.5-py2.4.egg\Products\CMFPlone\skins\plone_content\document_view.pt
Line 11, Column 4
Expression: <PathExpr standard:u'here/getText'>
Names:
{'container': <PloneSite at /Plone>,
 'context': <ATDocument at /Plone/mission-vision/index_html>,
 'default': <object object at 0x0108D528>,
 'here': <ATDocument at /Plone/mission-vision/index_html>,
 'loop': {},
 'nothing': None,
 'options': {'args': ()},
 'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x07909300>,
 'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://localhost:8080/mission-vision/index_html/document_view>,
 'root': <Application at >,
 'template': <FSPageTemplate at /Plone/document_view used for /Plone/mission-vision/index_html>,
 'traverse_subpath': [],
 'user': <SpecialUser 'Anonymous User'>}
Module zope.tales.expressions, line 217, in __call__ 
Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 163, in _eval 
Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 125, in render 
Module Products.Archetypes.ClassGen, line 56, in generatedAccessor 
Module wicked.fieldevent, line 29, in render 
Module zope.event, line 23, in notify 
Module zope.component.event, line 26, in dispatch 
Module zope.component._api, line 130, in subscribers 
Module zope.component.registry, line 290, in subscribers 
Module zope.interface.adapter, line 535, in subscribers 
Module wicked.fieldevent, line 16, in notifyFieldEvent 
Module zope.component._api, line 101, in getMultiAdapter 
Module zope.component._api, line 114, in queryMultiAdapter 
Module zope.component.registry, line 206, in queryMultiAdapter 
Module zope.interface.adapter, line 482, in queryMultiAdapter 
Module wicked.fieldevent.meta, line 78, in field_value 
Module Products.Archetypes.Field, line 1394, in get 
Module Products.Archetypes.BaseUnit, line 100, in transform 
Module Products.PortalTransforms.TransformEngine, line 181, in convertTo 
Module Products.PortalTransforms.chain, line 51, in convert 
Module Products.PortalTransforms.Transform, line 192, in convert
AttributeError: _v_transform
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: go to portal_setup, click import tab, select 'Portal Transforms' profile, checkbox 'PloneTransforms setup', hit 'Import selected steps', take care that 'Include dependencies' is checked, too.

References: http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Re-content-type-icons-missing-in-migrated-site-td2563285.html

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, Didn't work, got the same error after applying